# Can't find Code Explorer Window in Delphi 6 running on Windows 7 64-bit. How to get it back?

Tags: delphi, explorer, windows-7-x64, delphi-6

I'm having a really strange problem with the Delphi 6 IDE running on Windows 7 (64-bit edition).  I just can't find the Code Explorer window pane.  Usually it's docked against the left side of the Code Editor window.  If not there, then you can find it by opening the View menu and selecting Code Explorer.  But the Code Explorer is not docked to the Code Editor and when I drop down the View Menu the Code Explorer option is simply not there.  All the other options are: Project Manager, Object Inspector, Object TreeView, etc. but just not the Code Explorer.  Everything else about the IDE works great.  Has anybody else had this problem and if so, what can I do to get it back?  I rely on that view quite heavily.

Also, once I undock a view it doesn't seem to want to dock again.  I hover over the usual areas in the edit window and it won't accept it the orphaned view as a docking client.

-- roschler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record,
I had the same problem as you Robert.

Configuration:

- Delphi 6 Enterprise, installed to a custom location.
- Update Pack 2
- Several Third Party Components
- Windows 7, Spanish and English languages in Regional and language settings, and keyboard layout settings. Default language 'spanish',
  default keyboard distribution 'english'.

Issues:

- No 'code explorer' context menu item,
- In editor, no 'complete class at cursor'.
- Ctrl+Shift+C not working
- Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down Arrow not working.

I uninstalled Delphi, uninstalled English language, removed keymappings to change keyboard layout (Ctrl+Shift).

Then I installed Delphi again, custom location, execute the installer as administator -> no issues.
I installed the third party components -> no issues
To install the update pack, this time, I opened the exe with winrar, decompressed the file, changed the files 'setup.exe', '_ISDel.exe' and '_BDEL.EXE' to execute always as administrator for all users. Run 'setup.exe' as administrator.

I don't know exactly which step did the trick but now I have no Issues.

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce the missing Code Explorer menu item.  It works fine for me.

Regarding the non-dockable windows have you tried right clicking on the troublesome floating window and making sure that **Dockable** is ticked?

One thing to try when Delphi's IDE is giving you grief is to delete any .dsk files.

Finally, Delphi 6 pre-dates UAC and assumes that you can write to the installation directory.  Have you made sure that Delphi is able to do this one way or another?

Sorry I don't have a definitive answer, but this is all I can think of.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the .dsk file - most likely a window position off screen or something. Deleting these is the first step to normality.

Comment: Why should .dsk _hide_ View menu items? Off screen windows does make sense, but hidding menu entries is definitively strange...

Comment: @mj2008 @A.Bouchez Off screen windows doesn't explain it. I tried that. I don't really believe .dsk file is the issue, but it's so weird we are into guesswork territory.

Comment: I've tried deleting the DSK file, hand-editing it including editing the "docked" client list, everything.  It just won't come back.  In addition, the MessageView window is also having problems.  It is ignoring the settings in the DSK file.  I can tell because it's width is tiny and in the DSK file it's full screen width.  This is something else.  Delphi is able to write a delphi.$$$ to a Virtual Store directory.  Can it write to the install directory?  I believe so.  I've got it in a custom install directory to avoid UAC protection problems (not Program Files or Program Files(x86)).

Comment: @Robert If it's able to write to its install directory, why is there anything in the virtual store?

Comment: @David.  There's a file that the IDE insists on writing to "Program Files" despite not being installed there, called delphi.$$$ (yes dollar signs).  Oddly enough, the contents of this file too refers to elements in the "Program Files(X86)" directory such as this line from that file: "[C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\BORLAND\DELPHI6\OBJREPOS\OKCANCL1]", which looks like a repository line.  The file seems to be a temp version of an INI file for the IDE.  I checked the date/time and it gets updated every time I run the IDE.

Comment: @Robert Very strange: I've here Delphi 6 IDE freshly installed on a Win Seven 64bit OS. No sign of delphi.$$$ file anywhere in my system. Which third-party tool have you installed?

Comment: @A.Bouchez - Just GExperts as an extension.  A host of components but they shouldn't affect the IDE.  Maybe I'll try uninstalling GExperts temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried with Delphi 6 on Win64, and have all the windows. And all expected menu items. Sometimes, there is some problems of refresh, but when I restart the IDE, everything is back there.

But I've installed:

- Delphi 6 Suite Entreprise;
- Update pack 2;
- [DDevExtension](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/);
- [Delphi SpeedUp](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/delphispeedup/);
- [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/).

All is installed **not** in *C:\Program Files* but in a custom *C:\Progs* directory, which has all security rights set for all authenticated users. You should not install Delphi 6 under *C:\Program Files*, in all cases.

Works like a charm. Perhaps one of the add-ons fixed the issue.

Comment: My solution to the rights issue is to give the Borland folder under C:\Program Files (x86) full rights for Authenticated User.  The advice should be that the target users have sufficient rights to  write in the installation folder

Comment: I do not like an advice about not using CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES in favour of reinvented wheel.

Comment: I did install to a custom sub-directory (not Program Files, or Program Files(x86).  That's not the problem for me.

Comment: @Downvoter It's a matter of taste. The CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES expected by the IDE is not the one handled by the UAC. It's cleaner for me not to touch the original CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES rights, but create a folder dedicated to solve this compatibility issues. I first used the sub-directory trick, but I found out that you have redo the authorization every time an application write into CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES with Administrator rights, whereas using a separate dedicated folder like `C:\Progs` did not suffer for this issue. In short: IMHO updating is `C:\Progs` is cleaner than is ProgramFiles.

Comment: @Robert As I wrote in my answer, even the custom directory must have its rights opened for *all * authenticated users. It's not enough to create a custom directory separated from ProgramFiles, it should better also be accessible from any user (Administrator or not).

Comment: @A.Bouchez, distasteful, yes. Cleaner? You and @David Heffernan must be kidding me! How ignoring MS guidelines and polluting root is cleaner?

Comment: David Heffernan "not to have programs saving config there" is broken by given condition

Comment: @A.Bouchez - I'll check the rights on the custom install directory.  Good point.